# XeTeX not recognizing some commands, yet output is fine

Tags: xetex, arabic

I am trying an example of Arabic script in XeTeX. I use TeXstudio. The output is displayed fine, but there are some "unrecognized commands".

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\pagestyle{headings}

\title{مثال بسيط Example Simple}
\author{اسمي}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{القسم الأول}
هنا نبدأ باسم الله. وهذه كلمة انجليزية: Hi تعني: مرحباً.\\
\textenglish{I am here.} 
\end{document}
```

The unrecognized commands (highlighted in RED in TeXstudio) are: `\setmainlanguage, \newfontfamily\arabicfont` and `\textenglish`. There are NO error messages though.

Comment: The MWE is always appreciated, but perhaps some verbatim snippets of your error messages from the `.log` would also be helpful here.

Comment: There are no error messages!
"Process started: xelatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "Arabic".tex Process exited normally"
TexStudio highlight the above mentioned commands in RED. I have edited my question.

Comment: TeXStudio doesn't know all possible commands.

Comment: If so, how do TexStudio use the commands? or it just passes them to XeTex?

Comment: I doubt TeXStudio 'does' anything that sophisticated (but I've never used it).  If the document compiles fine, then I think egreg's point is that it uses a syntax highlighting that indicates when you might(!) be using an incorrect command, not that you are, for certain, using an incorrect command.  Do you get the same result when you have something like `\wencommnad`..?

Comment: \wencommnad ? what's this? it does not allow me to compile.

Comment: Your example is working fine with me. But I am not using TeXStudio, just TeXworks.

Comment: TeXstudio has a quite sophisticated system to highlight known and unknown commands, but sometimes the files used are not up-to-date or incomplete. You can extend them and change them: http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#CWLDESCRIPTION